# In Cursed Child, what House is Panju Weasley in?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In case you guys need a refresher, in *Harry Potter And The Cursed Child*, after Albus and Scorpius’ first attempt to save Cedric Diggory through interfering with the 1st Task, they discover that Ron had married Padma Patil and they had a son named Panju Weasley.

But what House was he Sorted into? He has a Gryffindor father and a Ravenclaw mother.

I think he may have Sorted into Gryffindor due to his mischievous behaviour, but is there any canon evidence to determine his Hogwarts House?

Comment: The lexicon says that they're in Gryffindor, but without any justification

Comment: Don’t you mean HE’S in Gryffindor? As in just Panju Weasley?

Comment: They as in "Panju is"

Comment: With you saying “They” to describe Panju, it’s like you’re saying he was born a GIRL. Is there anything in the Cursed Child to prove that?

Comment: You seem to be under the (mistaken) impression that my choice of pronoun to describe them (him) was somehow driven by gender.

Comment: Sorry, jumped to conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really have a way to know, but there is a scene in *The Cursed Child* (Act 2 Scene 9) that can hint to the answer:

> ALBUS: But how did I get sorted into Gryffindor?
>
> RON: You persuaded the Sorting Hat, don’t you remember? Panju bet you
> that you couldn’t get into Gryffindor if your life depended on it, so
> you chose Gryffindor to spite him. I can’t blame you, (dry) we’d all
> like to wipe the smile off his face sometimes, wouldn’t we?
> (Terrified.) Please don’t tell Padma I said that.

This dialogue reveals that the reason Albus was in the revised timeline in Gryffindor was because he wanted to prove Panju wrong. We can also understand that in Panju's opinion Gryffindor was his top choice and that according to him Albus wasn't worthy of being a Gryffindor.

So Panju was most likely in Gryffindor- He was determined to be in it, and we know that he could've asked the hat to be in it, like Albus did.